# RC2 Encryption With 20 Byte Key in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, openssl, rc2-cipher

I was given the requirement to implement RC2 encryption/decryption in an Asp.Net site. There is some data that needs to be shared with other systems securely and this is the encryption method already in use. I have tried a number of different approaches to this but all the implementations have default key lengths which can't be changed even though the algorithm allows variable key lengths (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2).

I'm looking to find out if I have overlooked something in my analysis or if there is a better option you could recommend.

**.Net Approach**

My first approach was to try and use the .NET RC2CryptoServiceProvider. This won't work because the key length is limited.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rc2.keysize.aspx

> "This algorithm supports key lengths from 40 bits to 1024 bits in
>   increments of 8 bits, but the RC2CryptoServiceProvider implementation
>   only supports key lengths from 40 bits to 128 bits in increments of 8
>   bits."

**OpenSSL.Net Approach**

There is a .NET wrapper of OpenSSL that I tried using. http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/

It worked fine but it only appears to support the default encryption functions and there is no way to change key length that I have found.

```
Cipher ciph = Cipher.RC2_CBC;
ciph.KeyLength = 20; // <---- Keylength cannot be assigned to it is readonly
CipherContext RC2 = new CipherContext(ciph);
```

**Call OpenSSL Directly**

I also tried calling OpenSSL through the command line by creating a process and grabbing the output. I ran into the same problem which is that the built in functions don't allow variable key lengths.

http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html

> The enc program only supports a fixed number of algorithms with
>   certain parameters. So if, for example, you want to use RC2 with a 76
>   bit key or RC4 with an 84 bit key you can't use this program.

Comment: @SLaks Your own link describes exactly the situation i'm in.
"I really can't see any upside to using RC2 for anything, the only use I can imagine that would make sense would be for compatibility with some ancient (in computer time) system."

Comment: I missed the second line in your question.  I deleted my comment.

Comment: If you can grab source code from somewhere (I saw an implementation in Mono) it's pretty easy to ensure that larger key sizes work. The key expansion routine is only [one page in the spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2268) - and it needs to have been implemented anyway.